# wordpress custom post type not linking to single-property.php and archive-property.php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

can someone check my code and see where i am going wrong please

```
<?php

// let's create the function for the custom type
function cmb_property_post_type() {
    // creating (registering) the custom type
    register_post_type( 'property', /* (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) */
        // let's now add all the options for this post type
        array('labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Properties', 'jointstheme'), /* This is the Title of the Group */
            'singular_name' => __('Property', 'jointstheme'), /* This is the individual type */
            'all_items' => __('All Properties', 'jointstheme'), /* the all items menu item */
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'jointstheme'), /* The add new menu item */
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Property', 'jointstheme'), /* Add New Display Title */
            'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'jointstheme' ), /* Edit Dialog */
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Property', 'jointstheme'), /* Edit Display Title */
            'new_item' => __('New Property', 'jointstheme'), /* New Display Title */
            'view_item' => __('View Property', 'jointstheme'), /* View Display Title */
            'search_items' => __('Search Property', 'jointstheme'), /* Search Custom Type Title */
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found in the Database.', 'jointstheme'), /* This displays if there are no entries yet */
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'jointstheme'), /* This displays if there is nothing in the trash */
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ), /* end of arrays */
            'description' => __( 'All properties are displayed in google maps', 'jointstheme' ), /* Custom Type Description */
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/', /* the icon for the custom post type menu */
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'properties', 'with_front' => false ), /* you can specify its url slug */
            'has_archive' => 'properties', /* you can rename the slug here */
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            /* the next one is important, it tells what's enabled in the post editor */
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions')
        ) /* end of options */
    ); /* end of register post type */

    /* this adds your post categories to your custom post type */
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'property_cat');
    /* this adds your post tags to your custom post type */
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'property_cat');

}

// adding the function to the Wordpress init
add_action( 'init', 'cmb_property_post_type');

/*
for more information on taxonomies, go here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
*/

// now let's add custom categories (these act like categories)
register_taxonomy( 'property_cat',
    array('property'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
    array('hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true, it acts like categories */
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Categories', 'jointstheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
            'singular_name' => __( 'Category', 'jointstheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories', 'jointstheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
            'all_items' => __( 'All Categories', 'jointstheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category', 'jointstheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'jointstheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category', 'jointstheme' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Category', 'jointstheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category', 'jointstheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name', 'jointstheme' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
        ),
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'property-cat' )
    )
);

// now let's add custom tags (these act like categories)
register_taxonomy( 'property_tag',
    array('property'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
    array('hierarchical' => false,    /* if this is false, it acts like tags */
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Tags', 'jointstheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
            'singular_name' => __( 'Tag', 'jointstheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags', 'jointstheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
            'all_items' => __( 'All Tags', 'jointstheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Tag', 'jointstheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tag:', 'jointstheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag', 'jointstheme' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag', 'jointstheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag', 'jointstheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name', 'jointstheme' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
        ),
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'property-tag' )
    )
);

function cmb_marker_properties( array $meta_boxes ) {

    $fields = array(
        array(
            'id'         => 'properties-marker',
            'name'       => '',
            'type'       => 'image',
            'file_type'  => 'image',
            'repeatable' => false,
            'sortable'   => true,
            'cols'       => 12
        )

    );

    $group_fields = $fields;
    foreach ( $group_fields as &$field ) {
        $field['id'] = str_replace( 'field', 'gfield', $field['id'] );
    }

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'    => 'Map Marker',
        'pages'    => 'property',
        'context'  => 'side',
        'priority' => 'low',
        'fields'   => array(
            array(
                'id' => 'cmb_marker_properties',
                //'name' => 'Add related links',
                'type' => 'group',
                'repeatable' => false,
                'sortable' => true,
                'fields' => $group_fields
            )
        )
    );

    return $meta_boxes;

}

add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'cmb_marker_properties' );



function cmb_info_properties( array $meta_boxes ) {

    $fields = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'properties-room',
            'name' => 'Room',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                '1' => '1',
                '2' => '2',
                '3' => '3',
                '4' => '4',
                '5' => '5',
                '6' => '6',
            ),
            'allow_none' => false,
            'cols'       => 12
        )
    );

    $group_fields = $fields;
    foreach ( $group_fields as &$field ) {
        $field['id'] = str_replace( 'field', 'gfield', $field['id'] );
    }

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'    => 'Property Details',
        'pages'    => 'property',
        'context'  => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'low',
        'fields'   => array(
            array(
                'id' => 'cmb_info_properties',
                //'name' => 'Add related links',
                'type' => 'group',
                'repeatable' => false,
                'sortable' => true,
                'fields' => $group_fields
            )
        )
    );

    return $meta_boxes;

}

add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'cmb_info_properties' );?>
```

i must of checked this numerous of times but i still cant see where the problem is or maybe i am just looking in the wrong place?

i have also created the single-property.php and the archive-property.php

the problem that i am getting is when i create posts within the property post type and click on publish then i click on view page, i get a 404 error.

the other problem and which i think is probably related to the above, i am unable to `wp_query` to query for within categories.

i tried using this code which didnt work:

```
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_cat',
            'term' => 'buy',
        )
    ),
);
```

what could be the problem and how do i fix it.

i tried the rewrite flush method and that didn't work either.

UPDATE: after re-saving the permalinks settings again. my custom post type pages have started going to the homepage. i am more confused

Comment: When you click **Properties** in thw WP-admin menu, what is the URL? I'm interested in the `post_type` part. Should look like: http://www.itheco.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=<example>. Sometimes when creating custom post types, you can accidentally create more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You have `has_archive => properties` which overrides the default post type `property`.

Change this:

```
'has_archive' => 'properties'
```

to:

```
'has_archive' => false
```

See [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)

Comment: that didnt work rahil. i was certain that by setting 'has_archive' => 'properties' i would be able to display my page custom post type using my custom archive page "archive-property.php"

Comment: Did you the flush rewrite rules?

Comment: i used this code but it still didnt work:
$set = get_option('post_type_rules_flased_property');
if ($set !== true){
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);
    update_option('post_type_rules_flased_property',true);
}

Comment: when i click "view page" after i published the page, this is the link i go to :
http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/properties/62-mexborough-street/
but it sometimes takes me to the homepage or to a 404 depending how i edit the "has_archive"

Comment: @Ahmed After edit `has_archive`. To update permalinks go to settings => permalinks and click save changes. The URL generated is what expected `localhost:8080/mywebsite/post-type/post-name`.

Comment: i went to settings=>permalinks, the Post name is already checked, i clicked save. i refreshed localhost:8080/mywebsite/properties/62-mexborough-street but it is still showing the homepage

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by using a different theme and applying the custom post type to it.

i think the way or the order of how i been adding my functions had something to do with my problem